# detect format used in a cpio archieve

Tags: unix

How do I detect the format used in a cpio archive?
I know when we exact contents from a cpio archive, it automatically detects the format.  However, I need to know what format is used.

For example, I have a file `A.cpio`, and I want to extract it, modify something, and then create a new `A.cpio`.  I need this new `A.cpio` to have the same format as the old one, since the functioning program using `A.cpio` may only understand some or one of the formats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are looking for `file` command

```
file x y
x: ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC)
y: ASCII cpio archive (pre-SVR4 or odc)
```

as per `man file`

> file — determine file type

gnu cpio use following format ( see https://www.gnu.org/software/cpio/manual/cpio.html#format ), to be used with `-H format`

- ‘bin’     The obsolete binary format. (2147483647 bytes)
- ‘odc’     The old (POSIX.1) portable format. (8589934591 bytes)
- ‘newc’     The new (SVR4) portable format, which supports file systems having more than 65536 i-nodes. (4294967295 bytes)
- ‘crc’     The new (SVR4) portable format with a checksum added.
- ‘tar’     The old tar format. (8589934591 bytes)
- ‘ustar’     The POSIX.1 tar format. Also recognizes GNU tar archives, which are similar but not identical. (8589934591 bytes)
- ‘hpbin’     The obsolete binary format used by HPUX’s cpio (which stores device files differently).
- ‘hpodc’     The portable format used by HPUX’s cpio (which stores device files differently).